# How to add text colours to the navbar in bootsrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I've been learning basic bootstrap for front-end web development. But I can't figure out how to change the color of navbar text items to blue color. I tried some of the online solutions for same the problem, but it didn't work out.
This is the code I've been working on:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white shadow fixed-top bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" alt="Site logo"> <!--edit--></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Statistics</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <?php if ($logged_user) { ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="register.php" title=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2.5a5.5 5.5 0 00-3.096 10.047 9.005 9.005 0 00-5.9 8.18.75.75 0 001.5.045 7.5 7.5 0 0114.993 0 .75.75 0 101.499-.044 9.005 9.005 0 00-5.9-8.181A5.5 5.5 0 0012 2.5zM8 8a4 4 0 118 0 4 4 0 01-8 0z"></path></svg>User</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.php" title=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3.25c0-.966.784-1.75 1.75-1.75h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v17.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5A1.75 1.75 0 013 20.75V3.25zm16.006 9.5l-3.3 3.484a.75.75 0 001.088 1.032l4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 000-1.032l-4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 00-1.088 1.032l3.3 3.484H10.75a.75.75 0 000 1.5h8.256z"></path></svg>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <span class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</span>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3.25c0-.966.784-1.75 1.75-1.75h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v17.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5A1.75 1.75 0 013 20.75V3.25zm9.994 9.5l3.3 3.484a.75.75 0 01-1.088 1.032l-4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 010-1.032l4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 011.088 1.032l-3.3 3.484h8.256a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-8.256z"></path></svg>Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've used bootstrap 5 here.
I want to add color #0d6efd to the text.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to change the color of active links:

```
.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, 
.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: #0d6efd;
}
```

Use the following for all the other links:

```
.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #0d6efd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-nav li a{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white shadow fixed-top bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" alt="Site logo"> <!--edit--></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Statistics</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <?php if ($logged_user) { ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="register.php" title=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2.5a5.5 5.5 0 00-3.096 10.047 9.005 9.005 0 00-5.9 8.18.75.75 0 001.5.045 7.5 7.5 0 0114.993 0 .75.75 0 101.499-.044 9.005 9.005 0 00-5.9-8.181A5.5 5.5 0 0012 2.5zM8 8a4 4 0 118 0 4 4 0 01-8 0z"></path></svg>User</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.php" title=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3.25c0-.966.784-1.75 1.75-1.75h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v17.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5A1.75 1.75 0 013 20.75V3.25zm16.006 9.5l-3.3 3.484a.75.75 0 001.088 1.032l4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 000-1.032l-4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 00-1.088 1.032l3.3 3.484H10.75a.75.75 0 000 1.5h8.256z"></path></svg>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <span class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</span>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3.25c0-.966.784-1.75 1.75-1.75h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v17.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5A1.75 1.75 0 013 20.75V3.25zm9.994 9.5l3.3 3.484a.75.75 0 01-1.088 1.032l-4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 010-1.032l4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 011.088 1.032l-3.3 3.484h8.256a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-8.256z"></path></svg>Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav li .nav-link{
color:#0d6efd
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white shadow fixed-top bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" alt="Site logo"> <!--edit--></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Statistics</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <?php if ($logged_user) { ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="register.php" title=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2.5a5.5 5.5 0 00-3.096 10.047 9.005 9.005 0 00-5.9 8.18.75.75 0 001.5.045 7.5 7.5 0 0114.993 0 .75.75 0 101.499-.044 9.005 9.005 0 00-5.9-8.181A5.5 5.5 0 0012 2.5zM8 8a4 4 0 118 0 4 4 0 01-8 0z"></path></svg>User</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.php" title=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3.25c0-.966.784-1.75 1.75-1.75h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v17.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5A1.75 1.75 0 013 20.75V3.25zm16.006 9.5l-3.3 3.484a.75.75 0 001.088 1.032l4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 000-1.032l-4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 00-1.088 1.032l3.3 3.484H10.75a.75.75 0 000 1.5h8.256z"></path></svg>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <span class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</span>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3.25c0-.966.784-1.75 1.75-1.75h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v17.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h5.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-5.5A1.75 1.75 0 013 20.75V3.25zm9.994 9.5l3.3 3.484a.75.75 0 01-1.088 1.032l-4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 010-1.032l4.5-4.75a.75.75 0 011.088 1.032l-3.3 3.484h8.256a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-8.256z"></path></svg>Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```